# How exactly a 'shutdown -h' "HALT" differ from "shutdown" in linux

Tags: linux

Suppose I have 20 process/deqamons running in my linux system,
How different the HALT will have an effect on my process/deamons, when compared to a SHUTDOWN

Answer (score 0):

Generally, one uses the [shutdown command](https://linux.die.net/man/8/shutdown). It allows a time delay and warning message before shutdown or reboot, which is important for system administration of multiuser shell servers; it can provide the users with advance notice of the downtime.

As such, the shutdown command has to be used like this to halt/switch off the computer immediately (on Linux and FreeBSD at least):

```
shutdown -h now
```

Or to reboot it with a custom, 30 minute advance warning:

```
shutdown -r +30 "Planned software upgrades"
```

After the delay, shutdown tells init to change to runlevel 0 (halt) or 6 (reboot). (Note that omitting  -h or -r will cause the system to go into single-user mode (runlevel 1), which kills most system processes but does not actually halt the system; it still allows the administrator to remain logged in as root.)

Once system processes have been killed and filesystems have been unmounted, the system halts/powers off or reboots automatically. This is done using the [halt](https://linux.die.net/man/8/halt) or reboot command, which syncs changes to disks and then performs the actual halt/power off or reboot.

On Linux, if halt or reboot is run when the system has not already started the shutdown process, it will invoke the shutdown command automatically rather than directly performing its intended action. However, on systems such as FreeBSD, these commands first log the action in wtmp and then will immediately perform the halt/reboot themselves, without first killing processes or unmounting filesystems.

Answer (score 0):

On POSIX systems the shutdown command switches runlevels, and executes the appropriate scripts.

On FreeBSD the "halt" command is an ACPI thing...

If you have particular concerns or would like to know things the general documentation wouldn't readily address, please feel free to refine your query.